# DRF Relation with two independent columns

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have DB structure like this:

```
common_org:
  id,
  code,
  title

special_org:
  id,
  code,
  address
```

Okay. For this I've created models:

```
class CommonOrg(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField()
  title = models.CharField()

class SpecialOrg(models.Model):
  code = models.CharField(null=True)
  address= models.CharField()
```

Now I want to output SpecialOrg as usual, but if I have `CommonOrg.code == SpecialOrg.code`, then attach CommonOrg to SpecialOrg like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "code": "XYZ",
  "address": "ADDRESS",
  "common_org": {
    "id": 2,
    "code": "XYZ",
    "title": "TITLE"
  }
}
```

Now I have solution with serializers.RelatedField:

```
class CommonOrgField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        class _CommonOrgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
            class Meta:
                model = CommonOrg
                fields = '__all__'

        representation = None

        try:
            common_org = CommonOrg.objects.get(code=value)
            representation = _CommonOrgSerializer(common_org).data
        except CommonOrg.DoesNotExist:
            pass

        return representation



class SpecialOrgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SpecialOrg
        fields = '__all__'

    common_org = CommonOrgField(read_only=True, source='code')
```

But it looks ugly for me.

So the question is: what is the right approach to implement it in DRF? Database is not mine and I cannot to alter it.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases where I am to add a read only field to a serializer, when the field is not related to the current model at database level, I'd use a serializer method field. You could use serializer method field like this in your case:

```
class SpecialOrgSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    common_org = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = SpecialOrg
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_common_org(self, obj):
        try:
            common_org = CommonOrg.objects.get(code=value)
        except CommonOrg.DoesNotExist:
            return None

        return _CommonOrgSerializer(common_org).data
```

Comment: Agreed, It looks much better. But I wonder about trick with model to exclude getting CommonOrg instance manually.

Comment: It might be tricky as there is no relation at the db level. Only, as the developer you know that the values of those fields being same means there is a relation between those two models. But to do this in a more generic way, you can continue with your path, and create a generic field for such cases by subclassing serializers.Field (or RelatedField). Your custom field in action might look like this in the end: common_org = RelatedByValueField(field_name='code', model=CommonOrg)